# What is the $\lim_{t\to 0^+}u(1,t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider $u_t=u_{xx}$ $x\in \mathbb{R}, t>0$

$
u(x,0) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{1,} &0\leq x\leq1 \\
       \text{0,} &\quad\text{otherwise.} \\ 
     \end{cases}
$

What is the $\lim_{t\to 0^+}u(1,t)$

Is the question complete? I mean no boundary conditions are given.

I know how to solve the problem when the boundary conditions are given. Here is the source from which I am studying http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolvingHeatEquation.aspx

Can somebody help me in finding the solution to this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the boundary values are given via the function $u(x,0)$. So what you have is a standard heat equation whose solution is obtained by the standard methods. It is:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\int_0^{\frac{1-x}{2\sqrt{t}}}e^{-s^2}\,ds+\int_0^{\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}}}e^{-s^2}\,ds\right)$$
Therefore
$$u(1,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}}e^{-s^2}\,ds$$
so that
$$\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}u(1,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s^2}\,ds=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I have never seen this formula before. In which book I can find this? I am reading from http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolvingHeatEquation.aspx He solves lot of cases but I did not encountered any formula like this?

Comment: By boundary condition, I meant things like $u(L,t)=0$ etc etc. This looks like the case where the rod is infinite

Comment: The problem statement says $∈ℝ$, so this is the infinite rod. Without a growth condition, solutions are not unique, and I don't think you can guarantee this value at $u(1,0+)$.